# What happens to the Seskii once the person they are loyal to dies?

Tags: numenera

We had a story arc that involved us saving a pregnant Seskii. We managed to, however we were unable to return in time to bond with the pups. However, for the sake of this question, let's say we did.

One of our PCs died recently. He went alone (hence why he died) on an espionage mission, and he would have likely gone without the Seskii, for the sake of stealth. The Corebook says:

> In terms of loyalty, seskii may become particularly devoted to anything and anyone, including other seskii, humans, statues that seem like creatures, and places they call home. They will fight to the death to defend a place or person they deem as their own.

In this situation, since the Seskii would not have been with him, it would have survived, but left without his master. What would happen then?

Comment: I can't find anything in the books. This one might be down to opinions.

Comment: Im not following you here. Is the character who died the object of devotion of the Seskii?

Comment: @ShadowKras yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### They would become really, really *sad*

And possibly even [depressed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_models_of_depression#Modeling_depression_in_animals) for their loss. But life goes on and they would probably (that's up to the GM) find a new goal in life again.

On a seriously note, the creatures social behavior was not fully disclosed by *Numenera* developers, so what really happens is subject to table variation. The GM could use real animal behaviors ([specially dogs](http://www.hrtwarming.com/10-most-loyal-dog-stories-ive-ever-heard-10-had-me-in-tears/)) as an example on how the *seskii* behave on similar situations.

But what normally happens is that the *seskii* will simply **wander the wilderness** after the dead companion is now gone:

> If a seskii in the wild is wearing manufactured armor, it means the creature was once someone’s favored companion. There is a good chance that the person is now long dead, as a seskii would not leave her side while she lived.